# Load word2vec model that is in .tar format

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, tar.gz

I want to load a previously trained word2vec model into gensim. The trouble is the file format. It is not a .bin file format but a .tar file. It is the model / file  *deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar.gz* from the [University of Leipzig](https://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/German). The model is also listed [on HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/inovex/Word2Vec-Finetuning-Service-Base-Models) where different word2vec models for English and German are listed.

**First I tried:**

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar.gz')
```

--> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M

**Then I unzipped the file with 7-Zip and tried the following:**

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar')
```

--> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load('deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar')
```

--> UnpicklingError: could not find MARK

Then I got a bit desperate...

```
import gensim.downloader
model = gensim.downloader.load('deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar')
```

--> ValueError: Incorrect model/corpus name

Googling around I found useful information how to load a .bin model with gensim ( [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549248/how-to-load-a-pre-trained-word2vec-model-file-and-reuse-it/39662736#39662736) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65394022/how-can-a-word2vec-pretrained-model-be-loaded-in-gensim-faster) ). Following this [thread](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/4150) it seems tricky to load a .tar file with gensim. Especially if one has not one .txt file but five .txt files as in this case. I found [one answer how to read a .tar file but with tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733191/how-to-read-and-load-tarfile-to-extract-feature-vector). Since I am not familiar with tensorflow, I prefer to use gensim. Any thoughts how to solve the issue is appreciated.

Comment: @possum: not sure why gensim needed to be deleted from the title. Seems a  bit arbitrary?... especially since this is the only change made. The random words at the bottom were not deleted. I just deleted them :-)

Comment: Expanding a `.tar` archive – the core challenge here – is a generic task that really has nothing to do with Gensim (which does bot tend to use `.tar` files in any role). Further, the specific data archives in question don't have any Gensim-specific files or formats inside. So none of the challenges here are inherently`gensim`-related. (The other implicit goal, "find me something that *would* work in Gensim", isn't really the thrust of the question per the rest of the title.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.tar` file is a bundle of one or more directories and files – see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing) – and thus not the sort of single-model file that you should expect Gensim to open directly.

Rather, similar to as with a `.zip` file, you'd use some purpose-specific software to extract any content inside the `.tar` into individual files – then point Gensim at those, individually, *if* they're formats Gensim understands.

A typical command-line operation to extract the individual file(s) from a `.tar.gz` file (which is both tarred & gzipped) would be:

tar -xvzf deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar.gz

That tells the command to e`x`tract with `v`erbose reporting while also un-g`z`ipping the `f`ile `deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar.gz`. Then you'll have one or more new local files, which are the actual (not-packaged-up) files of interest.

In some graphical UI file-explorers, like the MacOS 'Finder', simply double-clicking to perform the default 'open' action on `deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M.tar.gz` will perform this expansion (no `tar` command-line needed).

But note: the University of Liepzig page you've linked describes these files as 'corpora' (training texts), *not* trained sets of word-vectors or word2vec models.

And I looked at the "2019 - switzerland - public web file" you're referring-to, and inside is a directory (folder) `deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M`, with 7 `.txt` files inside of various formats, and 1 `.sql`  file. But none of those are any sort of trained word-vectors - just text & text-statistics.

You could use those to train a model yourself. The `deu-ch_web-public_2019_1M-sentences.txt` is closest to what you need, as 1 million plain-text sentences.

But it's still not yet in a form fully ready for word2vec training. Each line has a redundant line-number at the front, and the text hasn't yet been tokenized into word-tokens (which would potentially remove punctuation, or sometimes keep punctuation as distinct tokens). And, as a mere 15 million words total, it's still fairly small as a corpus for creating a powerful word2vec model.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond and explain tar files. It will be useful for others who are not familiar with .tar files and unzipping. 
Indeed I got several .txt files (see my initial question). Thanks for looking at them. If this is "just" a corpus that would need training and NOT a trained model, better to use [DevMount's pre-trained word2vec](https://devmount.github.io/GermanWordEmbeddings/) or Spacy's pre-trained [de_core_news_md](https://spacy.io/models/de) model. Got them running but wanted to compare models.

Answer (score 1):

Following gojomo's comment I decided to use DevMount's and Spacy's pre-trained German models to find synonyms. First the models need to be downloaded and unzipped. See posts above. DevMount's model can be downloaded [here](https://devmount.github.io/GermanWordEmbeddings/). Spacy has three pre-trained German models. They can be downloaded [here](https://spacy.io/models/de). In the spirit of sharing, below is the code I implemented.

**DevMount's Model**

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

# Load pre-trained Word2Vec model.
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('german.model', binary = True)
#get most similar word for Vertrauen
model.most_similar(model['Vertrauen'])
#get most similar word for Vertrauen but delineate it from word Mutter
model.most_similar(model['Vertrauen']-model['Mutter'])
#get embedding coordinates for Vertrauen
model['Vertrauen']
```

**Spacy**

```
import numpy as np
import spacy

model = spacy.load('de_core_news_md')

keyWord = 'Vertrauen'

ms = model.vocab.vectors.most_similar(
    np.asarray([model.vocab.vectors[model.vocab.strings[keyWord]]]), n=10)
words = [model.vocab.strings[w] for w in ms[0][0]]
distances = ms[2]
print(words)
```

--> The models `de_core_news_sm` and `de_core_news_lg` threw unpickling and/or key errors in my case. So decided to use `de_core_news_md`.

Also discovered [LeoLM from LAION](https://laion.ai/blog/leo-lm/). It is a German Foundation Language Model built on Llama-2. So it is an open-source large language model (LLM). The model can be downloaded  but has an online interface on [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/LeoLM). As an LLM it can, amongst other things, be queried for synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to load a `gensim` model.

First, extract the content of the compressed `.tar` file.

Then, if the content is a `.txt` file:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/user/file.txt')
```

If the file is a `.model` file:

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

content = "/home/user/file.word2vec.model"

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(content)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I saw this solution already on [GitHub](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/4150). I mentioned it in my question. The trouble is that I have 4 txt files, not one. Following the labeling and formatting of the txt files I cannot make out which one I should take or whether I should combine them and if so, which ones I should combine.